# Scrapy / Form request to the next page, callback does not go to the next function

Tags: web-scraping, callback, scrapy

recently i started studying about scrapy and web scraping. I'm working on my first project and i got stucked. I would appreciate if someone can help me with the problem :)

Im scraping the page http://esg.krx.co.kr/contents/02/02020000/ESG02020000.jsp

So far i got to the moment where my program scrapes all the 77pages (i know its a bit hardcoded, i will try to change it later on) and get's the company_name and company_share_id. So now i'm trying to go to the company_page_url and again send a post request to get the data from the graph (not every company has the graph). However it seems like it doesn't call the parse_company_result.

Below i upload my code:

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.http import Request


class EsgKrx1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'esg_krx1'
allowed_domains = ['esg.krx.co.kr']

def start_requests(self):
    #sending a post request to the web
    return [scrapy.FormRequest("http://esg.krx.co.kr/contents/99/ESG99000001.jspx",
                               formdata={'sch_com_nm': '',
                                         'sch_yy': '2021',
                                         'pagePath': '/contents/02/02020000/ESG02020000.jsp',
                                         'code': '02/02020000/esg02020000',
                                         'pageFirstCall': 'Y'},
                               callback=self.parse)]

def parse(self, response):
    url = "http://esg.krx.co.kr/contents/99/ESG99000001.jspx"

    total_pages = 77
    for page in range(total_pages):
        payload = {
            'sch_com_nm': '',
            'sch_yy': '2021',
            'pagePath': '/contents/02/02020000/ESG02020000.jsp',
            'code': '02/02020000/esg02020000',
            'curPage': str(page+1)
        }

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=url,
                                 method='POST',
                                 formdata=payload,
                                 callback=self.parse_result)

def parse_result(self, response):
    dict_data = json.loads(response.text)

    # looping in the result and assigning the company name
    for i in dict_data['result']:
        company_name = i['com_abbrv']
        compay_share_id = i['isu_cd']
        print(company_name, compay_share_id)

        company_page_url = f"http://esg.krx.co.kr/contents/02/02010000/ESG02010000.jsp?isu_cd={compay_share_id}"
        yield Request(company_page_url)

        data_url = "http://esg.krx.co.kr/contents/99/ESG99000001.jspx"

        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }

        # yield response.follow(url=data_url, method='POST', callback=self.parse_company_result, headers=headers)
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=data_url,
                                 method='POST',
                                 headers=headers,
                                 callback=self.parse_company_result)


def parse_company_result(self, response):
    graph_data = json.loads(response.text)
    print(graph_data)
```

All the functions are of course in the class, it just didn't paste the code as i expected.

So my question is:

How do i go to the company page url?

Or maybe the request is correct, but later i do something wrong?

Maybe i don't get the response from the data_url?

I will appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your script as there were quite a few errors, namely:

1. In `parse_result` it's best to create another function to parse the company urls as opposed to parsing them in the same one.
2. You need to include the payload to parse the json from the `Request Url`, again it's best to split these into separate parsers that way you can see what is happening and what is going on.

I have built a scraper that does this in a hierarchical way so that you can understand what's happening top-down.

Additional note:

- `cb_kwargs` allows you to take variables from one parser to another. Therefore, I can grab the company id and name from `parse_result` and yield this in the last parser. Note - the company id was important for the payload in `parse_company`. Therefore, you should get used to learning how `cb_kwargs` works.

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.http import Request

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Origin': 'http://esg.krx.co.kr',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'http://esg.krx.co.kr/contents/02/02010000/ESG02010000.jsp?isu_cd=004710',
}

class EsgKrx1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'esg_krx1'
    allowed_domains = ['esg.krx.co.kr']
    
    def start_requests(self):
        #sending a post request to the web
        return [scrapy.FormRequest("http://esg.krx.co.kr/contents/99/ESG99000001.jspx",
                                formdata={'sch_com_nm': '',
                                            'sch_yy': '2021',
                                            'pagePath': '/contents/02/02020000/ESG02020000.jsp',
                                            'code': '02/02020000/esg02020000',
                                            'pageFirstCall': 'Y'},
                                callback=self.parse)]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        url = "http://esg.krx.co.kr/contents/99/ESG99000001.jspx"
    
        total_pages = 77
        for page in range(total_pages):
            payload = {
                'sch_com_nm': '',
                'sch_yy': '2021',
                'pagePath': '/contents/02/02020000/ESG02020000.jsp',
                'code': '02/02020000/esg02020000',
                'curPage': str(page+1)
            }
    
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=url,
                                    method='POST',
                                    formdata=payload,
                                    callback=self.parse_result)
    
    def parse_result(self, response):
        dict_data = json.loads(response.text)
    
        # looping in the result and assigning the company name
        for i in dict_data['result']:
            company_name = i['com_abbrv']
            company_share_id = i['isu_cd']

            company_page_url = f"http://esg.krx.co.kr/contents/02/02010000/ESG02010000.jsp?isu_cd={company_share_id}"
            yield Request(company_page_url,
            #headers=headers, 
            callback = self.parse_company, cb_kwargs = {
                'company_share_id':company_share_id,
                'company_name':company_name
            })

    def parse_company(self, response, company_share_id, company_name):
    """ Grab the chart ID from the webpage and store it as a list"""

        chart_id = response.xpath("(//div[@class='CHART-AREA'])[1]//div//@id").get()
        chart_id = [chart_id.split("chart")[-1]]

""" Notice that the number at the end of code in payload changes for each chart"""    

        for id_of_chart in chart_id:
            for code_no in  range(1, 3):
                yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                    url = 'http://esg.krx.co.kr/contents/99/ESG99000001.jspx',
                    method='POST',
                    # headers=headers,
                    formdata = {
                            'url_isu_cd': str(company_share_id),
                            'isu_cd': '',
                            'sch_com_nm': '',
                            'pagePath': '/contents/02/02010000/ESG02010000.jsp',
                            'code': f'02/02010000/esg02010000_0{code_no}',
                            'chartNo': f'{id_of_chart}'
                                                                    },
                    callback = self.parse_company_result,
                    cb_kwargs = {
                        'company_share_id':company_share_id,
                        'company_name':company_name
                    }
                )
        
    def parse_company_result(self, response, company_share_id, company_name):
        graph_data = json.loads(response.text)
        yield {
            'data':graph_data, 
            'company_name':company_name,
            'company_share_id':company_share_id
        }
```

Output:

```
{'data': {'block1': [{'yy': '2019', 'pnt0': '7', 'pnt1': '2', 'pnt2': 'null'}, {'yy': '2020', 'pnt0': '7', 'pnt1': '2', 'pnt2': 'null'}, {'yy': '2021', 'pnt0': '7', 'pnt1': '2', 'pnt2': 'null'}]}, 'company_name': '아남전자', 'company_share_id': '008700'}

...
...
```

Comment: Hey! At first i want to thank you so much for that, well i definitely understand now how to use the cb_kwargs. The code is really clear for me and as a beginner i love the way its written. However i think it doesn't exactly do what it's supposed at the end. After going to the company_page_url it should send a request to the .jspx. In the formdata you used some kind of 'bldcode' - i don't understand that, and actually it does not extract the data from the .jspx So the graph_data actually shows the data from the main page, not from the company_page_url. All the company urls in the .jspx file ->>

Comment: have a unique chartNo, which as i guess you assigned as bldcode. I guess thats why it can not get the data from the graph? // I really appreciate your help! @dollar bill

Comment: Okay after checking detailed the company url i think the problem is that on network tab we have a few .jspx file and the request is sent correctly, but it just goes to the wrong .jspx file. I guess i need to find a way how to get to the specific .jspx.       I will keep all the comments, hopefully someone in the future can use it as a lecture.

Comment: @Matiimov Silly mistake on my end as I was on a haste. Check the updated code - it's much easier than you'd think. If you think this answers your question please accept it as an answer.

Comment: Of course i do accept is as an answer! Yeah i totally agree that the code is really understandable and very clear. I still need 2 reputation to be able to vote for the answers, but you have my word as soon as i can vote, ill come back here and do it! Thanks once again!

Comment: Hey, could you please explain me why in the parse_company you used loop 
for id_of_chart in chart_id:
            for code_no in  range(1, 3):... ?
I think i fully dont understand only this part.

Comment: @Matiimov there are two charts on a page when they exist and so the payload would append the value 1 for chart 1 or a value 2 for chart 2. The range just grabs the values 1, 2 for each graph and stores it into the payload to grab both charts. You can remove this if you only need graph 1 or graph 2 and just use one of the two values in the code.